# Why does \Sentence not return 1 when used in the middle of a paragraph?

Tags: lists, enumerate, koma-script, legal-style, scrjura

I am writing a contract and would like to use the `\Sentence` command. This works well, if I start with the numbering right after starting a new paragraph, but it fails when I am trying to get 1/a in the middle of it.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrjura}

\renewcommand*{\thesentence}{\alph{sentence}}
\renewcommand{\sentencenumberformat}{\thesentence)~}

\begin{document}
\begin{contract}
\Clause{title={Clause}}
\Sentence Test1
\Sentence Test2
\Sentence Test3

Test
\Sentence Why not a
Test
\Sentence Why not b

\end{contract}
\end{document}
```

gets me

[image: Output]

but I would like to get a) when I call `\Sentence` the first time.

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit late to ask. But what are you trying to do? Doing sentence numbering manually will lead to errors. Doesn't the machinery work the way you expected? What happened?

Comment: The problem is, I was copying a contract, that for whatever reason had lead texts, that did not count as a sentence. So I wanted to introduce automatic sentence numbering, but expected it to let me decide, where a sentence starts.

Comment: So `\newcommand{\mysentence}{\setcounter{sentence}{0}\Sentence}` (untested) would have been enough?

Comment: @KeksDose probably yes. If this does not cause issues with counter resetting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the KOMA classes is partial and, in some places, inaccurate. In this case, there is very scanty coverage of `\Sentence`. Apparently 'semi-automatic' numbering is supported. As far as I can tell, this means the sentence number is reset and incremented at the start of each paragraph. The code distinguishes the use of `\Sentence` at the start of a paragraph so the number is not incremented twice, but there seems to be no obvious way to prevent the automatic increment without disabling the automatic numbering of paragraphs as well. Given the purpose of sentence numbering is to number sentences, I suppose this is not altogether unreasonable: only at the start of a paragraph do you have the first sentence. Once the paragraph is started, the number must be two or more.

The approach recommended in the documentation for numbering with lowercase letters is to use the package `enumerate` or `enumitem` which support customised `enumerate` environments.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrjura}
\renewcommand*{\thesentence}{\alph{sentence}}
\renewcommand*{\sentencenumberformat}{\thesentence)~}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tbsclause}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[tbsclause]{label=\alph*)}
\begin{document}
\begin{contract}
  \Clause{title={Clause}}
  \begin{tbsclause}
    \item Test1
    \item Test2
    \item Test3
  \end{tbsclause}
  
  Test
  \begin{tbsclause}
    \item Why not a
    Test
    \item Why not b
  \end{tbsclause}
\end{contract}
\end{document}
```

[image: sentence numbering from 1]

If the syntax is too awkward, I'd recommend rolling your own version of `\Clause` etc. with a simple `enumitem` setup. This is the sane, sensible and safe approach.

---

If you prefer to live dangerously, think sanity is overrated and don't mind your documents going haywire for mysterious reasons at inconvenient times, and want to persist with the `\Sentence` approach, note the following.

1. **The hack below is very likely to break if the package is updated.** I tried to find a way to alter some less substantial definition or to patch this one, but failed on both counts. Perhaps somebody else with a better understanding of these things (not hard) will do better.
2. **It is a brute force-and-ignorance approach, highly likely to cause other problems.** You would need to scrutinise the results with eagle eyes.

### *Caveat emptor!!*

---

Again, if you **must** do this in this way, an *extremely dirty* workaround would be to add the following to your preamble after loading `scrjura`.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\contract@everypar}{%
  \ifparnumber
    \ifx\scrjura@special@par\relax
      \ifx\scrjura@special@reset@par\relax\else
        \global\let\thepar\scrjura@special@reset@par
        \global\let\scrjura@special@reset@par\relax
      \fi
      \refstepcounter{par}%
%       \refstepcounter{sentence}% 
    \else
      \ifx\scrjura@special@reset@par\relax
        \global\let\scrjura@special@reset@par\thepar
      \fi
      \global\let\thepar\scrjura@special@par
      \global\let\scrjura@special@par\relax
      \setcounter{sentence}{0}\refstepcounter{sentence}%
    \fi
    \begingroup
      \if@filesw
        \protected@write\@auxout{%
          \expandafter\let\csname \scrjura@env@type @Clauseformat\endcsname
          \@firstofone
        }{%
          \string\newmaxpar{\scrjura@env@type}%
                           {\csname the\scrjura@env@type
                             AbsoluteClause\endcsname}%
                           {\thepar}%
        }%
      \fi
      \getmaxpar\@tempa{\scrjura@env@type}%
                       {\csname the\scrjura@env@type AbsoluteClause\endcsname}%
      \typeout{Stored max is \@tempa}%
      \def\reserved@a##1\@nnil{\def\@tempa{##1}}%
      \afterassignment\reserved@a\@tempcnta=0\@tempa\relax\@nnil
      \ifnum \@tempcnta>\@ne
        {\usekomafont{parnumber}{\parformat\parformatseparation}}%
      \else
        \def\reserved@a{\relax}%
        \ifx\@tempa\reserved@a
          \withoutparnumber
        \else
          {\usekomafont{parnumber}{\parformat\parformatseparation}}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \endgroup
  \else
    \begingroup\withoutparnumber\endgroup
    \setcounter{sentence}{-1}\refstepcounter{sentence}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Note that I am not going to provide compilable code here. If you do not know how to use the above fragment, you certainly should not be trying to do so.

[image: numbering from 1]

Comment: You can't replace \Clause with some enumitem environment. The clauses of scrjura.sty have some more features than just reseting the numbering of paragraphs. I can't find a hint in scrguide (ok, in Englisch: scrguien) about replacing anything of scrjura with enumitem.

Comment: @KeksDose Section 10.8 uses `enumerate` and cites `enumitem` and an alternative. The example there uses the `enumerate` package for alphabetic labels in a `scrjura`-based listing of club bylaws. This is in the English version of `scrguide`, so I'm not sure what you're looking at if. In any case, my suggestion to use `enumitem` is definitely supported by the documentation for `scrjura`. That example doesn't replace `\Clause`, but I only suggested that if the syntax I proposed was unacceptable and as better than redefining internals. I *recommended* using `tbsclause` inside `\Clause`s.